# Beetle Identification / able to retract its head

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

I can't find any identification of this beetle online. The closest guess I got to it is "Hister beetle" but the rough surfaces on its shell make me think otherwise.

The most common behavior is that when feeling threatened, it plays dead for some time. It retract its head, and then covers it with its 2 front limbs, which make it look like a piece of wood or a tree seed.

Here's a video showing its movement
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSjQ_8vbYw4

Philippines, Southeast Asia.
under tropical savanna climate

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this creature. The location can be an essential clue for identifications. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Based on Arthur J Frost's comment, Trox Beetles more likely resemble it in movement and behavior. So it's probably more like a member of Trogidae beetle family.

Comment: Um, no.  I'm not completely sure, but the Scarab family Trogidae (the Skin Beetles) looks more likely to me (see [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/5824) for photos of some North American species; the family is worldwide).

Comment: You're right. I saw some videos about it on youtube which greatly resemble the movement, including the behavior of playing dead, retracting its head(not sure if it's the right term) and covering it with their front limbs. Though this is probably just one of the types under it, since one video shows it's able to produce sound when playing dead, but this one is not.